# How to make the eigenvalue of this matrix inside or on the unit circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Vector autoregressive process is defined by:
$$X_{t} = \sum_{p=0}^{P}A_pX_{t-p}+\epsilon_t$$
I want to know how to generate the real value $A_p$s so that the eigenvalue of the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_1 & A_2 & \dots  & A_p \\
    I & O &  \dots  & O \\
    O & I & \dots& O  \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
are all inside or on the unit circle.
I tried to divide the $A_p$s by the maximum eigenvalue of $\sum A_p$ so that 1 is an eigenvalue of this matrix but there is no guarantee that 1 is the largest eigenvalue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to randomly generate such matrices, then you can proceed as follows. We construct the $(a_i)$ s.t. $\rho(A)=\alpha$ where $\alpha >0$ is given.

Note that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(x)=x^n-a_1x^{n-1}-a_2x^{n-2}-\cdots$.

1. You randomly choose the list $V=(a_i)$. For example (if $n=4$), let

$V=[4, 2, -5, -9]$.

2. You calculate the associated $\rho(A)$; here $\rho(A)\approx 4.054$.
3. Let $q(x)=(\dfrac{\alpha}{\rho(A)})^np(\dfrac{\rho(A)}{\alpha} x)$. For $\alpha =\rho(A)/4$, we obtain $q(x)=x^4-x^3-(1/8)x^2+(5/64)x+9/256$.
4. Finally we obtain for the $(a_i)$: $[1,1/8,-5/64,-9/256]$.

Note that there are well-known polynomials that have all their roots in the unit disc, but they are not random.

EDIT. Assume that the $(A_j)$ are $k\times k $ matrices. We want to obtain a matrix s.t. $\rho(A)\approx 1$.

1. Randomly choose the $(A_i)$.

   2. Calculate $\rho(A)$.
   3. Iterate that follows

$A_1=\dfrac{1}{\rho(A)}A_1,A2=\dfrac{1}{\rho(A)^{2}}A_2,A_3=\dfrac{1}{\rho(A)^{3}}A_3,\cdots$.

Calculate $\rho(A)$.

Comment: Thanks, the $A_p$s are matrices but I get the idea.

Comment: Characteristic polynomials can be computed by symbolic methods and then the derivative of square error between current coefficients and the target coefficients w.r.t the entries of matrices can be computed by automatic differentiation library, so the matrices can be obtained by gradient descent. However for large matrices, the symbolic method for calculating characteristic polynomial is too slow.

Comment: Why make it simple when we can make it complicated? You did not understand my post. See my edit.

Comment: Ow,  should it be $A_k = \frac{1}{\rho(A) ^ k}A_k$? The form of the eigenvector is [$v$, $v/\lambda$, $v/\lambda^2$, ...], so divide each $A_k$ by $\rho^k$ ensures that [$v$, $v\rho/\lambda$, ...] is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda/\rho$.

Comment: @Ziqian Xie , you are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you, white wolf!